# reading from a json file using python

Tags: python, json

Im trying to read from this json file and print the values. I cant find out how to print all the values from the first (dictonary-index?) in the list.

I want to print the following:

- website: https://www.amazon.com/Apple-iPhone-GSM-Unlocked-64GB/dp/B07
- price: 382,76

How can i do it?

JSON file:

```
[
  {
   "website": "https://www.amazon.com/Apple-iPhone-GSM-Unlocked-64GB/dp/B078P5BK5G",
   "price": "382,76"
  },
  {
   "website": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-iPhone-8-Plus-GSM-Unlocked-64GB-Gold-Renewed-Gold-64-GB-Gold-64-GB-/143340730792",
   "price": "609,15"
  }
]
```

Python code:
Tried this

```
import json

with open('./result.json') as json_file:  
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for p in data:
                print(p["price"])
```

Output is the prices of the products:

382,76
609,15

Instead of printing the prices it should print the values in the first dict in the list. Any good tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You are looping over the list of dictionaries. If you want to loop over the values of the first dictionary, you first need to get the first element, and loop over that one.

```
first_dict = data[0]
for value in first_dict.values():
    print(value)
```